# Restarting tomcat service through java/servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

i want to restart my tomcat through my java code/servlet.
Is there any way to do so??? 
ON particular Exception,i want to restart my tomcat

Comment: restart using the same JVM or completly shut-down the JVM and restart using a new one? BTW: Which operating system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to run any application. In my code i m just executing my BATCH file.
Here is a code for the same:

**Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start C:\restart_tomcat.bat");**

And following is my '**restart_tomcat.bat**' file contains

C:\WINDOWS\system32\net stop TomcatServiceName 
  C:\WINDOWS\system32\net start TomcatServiceName
  exit

Answer (score 1):

may be you should write an external program that will execute the scripts shutdown.sh/startup.sh (CATALINA_HOME/bin) and call it when an exception occurs

Answer (score 1):

If you have the manager application installed you can use it to [stop](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Stop_an_Existing_Application) and [start](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Start_an_Existing_Application) individual deployed applications. Note that you don't want to get an application to ask the manager to stop and then restart *itself* for obvious reasons. Instead you could have a proxy-manager app which will would accept requests to stop and then restart other apps. Your app would then make requests to the proxy-manager.